# is there a way to dynamically make array list of yaml in tmuxinator?

Tags: tmuxinator

I would like to use tmuxinator for my work.
I have a folder which has several files not more than 6-7 files.
I want tmuxinator to be configured such that tmux has a window with splitted panes all of which are assigned to a specific file in the folder.

tmuxinator project goes as follows:

```
name: case
root: <%= ENV["PWD"] %>
windows:
    setup:
        panes:
            - < this list should change dynamically>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it provides loop block as follows:

```
<%- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`.split("\n").each do |item| %>
- <%= item.chomp %>: vim <%= item %>
<%- end >
```

Thus, the previous my question would be

```
name: case
root: <%= ENV["PWD"] %>
windows:
    setup:
        panes:
            <%- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`.split("\n").each do |item| %>
            - <%= item.chomp %>: vim <%= item %>
            <%- end >
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, arguably more flexible option, would be to pass the list of files to tmuxinator using CLI args.

For example, you could change your project config file to the following:

```
name: case
windows:
  - setup:
        panes:
            <%- args.each do |file| %>
              - vim <%= file %>
            <%- end %>
```

... and then start tmuxinator using: `tmuxinator start case $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)`